# len() compared with __len__ on numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

What is going on here? How can I check that `a` has length?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(3)
>>> hasattr(a , '__len__')
True
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Here, python considers `a` to not have length:

```
>>>a.shape
()
```

I am using python 2.7.3 and  numpy 1.8.0.

Thanks.

Comment: Yair, both the title and this [2nd revision of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26475863/revisions) deleted part of your question, so the answer appears unconnected to the question. Can you please fix it? It's very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, maybe I am missing something here, but why don't you check for types?

```
import numpy as np

def make_ary(item):
    if not isinstance(item, list):
        ary = np.array([item])
    else:
        ary = np.array(item)
        ary = ary.ravel()
    return ary
```

And then:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = 3
c = [ [1] , [2] ,[3] ]


>> make_ary(a)
array([1, 2, 3])

>> make_ary(b)
array([3])

>> make_ary(c)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that was solved by a mysterious stranger that erased their comment. I'll just use `np.ravel`.